# How can I load an activity from my App on incoming VoIP call?

Tags: java, android, voip

I'm building an android app with a `VoIP` functionality integrated. What I want to achieve is like even when the app is closed and when `User1` calls `User2` then in `User2` mobile my `CallActivity` from my app is opened.

What I want to achieve is similar to *WhatsApp* call feature. Even if WhatsApp is closed then when someone calls us, then the call is notified to us.

Can somebody please guide me in achieving this?

Comment: Did you try something? Where is your code?

Comment: @GauravMall Calling functionality is working within the app environment. I just want it to work even outside the app.

Comment: What you are looking for then is a `Service`. Try looking it up on the documentation.

Comment: @GauravMall Okay

Comment: Did the answer work?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually follow the official Google documentation on how to build a calling app. Instead of making a custom `Service` they provide an already built-in `Service` from Google. It is called `ConnectionService`. To use it just put this in your manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.example.MyConnectionService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Because your question is too broad, I can't post specific code for your application. You have to build it yourself. So, look at the documentation:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged

Comment: Thanks @GauravMall I will check it out.